# Filters in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use a pattern based filter in my routes file.

I want to stop anything without crsf and only allow ajax calls.

So far I have:

```
Route::when('/gateway/*', 'crsf');
```

I'm not sure where im going wrong and how i could add in the ajax verification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Route Groups` to apply `before filter`.
http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups

You can check if a request is ajax or not by calling `if(Request::ajax)`. Define this on your `before` call.
http://laravel.com/docs/requests

As for the patterns, have a look at `Pattern Based Filters` section of Routing documentation.
http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Comment: Thanks can you give me an example of how to define the ajax on the before call?

Comment: Also I have looked at pattern based filters in the docs, not sure where to add in what the filter is?

Comment: Create a filter. Make it like; "return Request::ajax();". Then apply that filter to before method.

Comment: But I don;t want it in a before method, I want it as a pattern based filter.